# Connector[HTTP/1.1-8081] Error while running two projects in STS simultaneously

Tags: spring-boot, tomcat, microservices

I am trying to run 2 Microservices projects using two instances of STS (sts-4.4.2.RELEASE). Once First project is up and running , I try to run the second project and get below error.
I have specified two different ports for these 2 projects via VM Agruments :

*-Dserver.port=8055*

*-Dserver.port=8088*

Looks like 8081 port is configured in Tomcat or any other configuration internally. Could you please help/suggest.

**Error log :**

{"mdc":{},"timestamp":"2020-05-16 11:20:07.317","level":"ERROR","logger":"org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService","message":"Failed to start connector **[Connector[HTTP/1.1-8081]]**","exception":"\r\norg.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [Connector[HTTP/1.1-8081]]\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:167)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.addConnector(StandardService.java:225)\r\n\tat org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.addPreviouslyRemovedConnectors(TomcatWebServer.java:261)\r\n\tat org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.start(TomcatWebServer.java:198)\r\n\tat org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.startWebServer(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:311)\r\n\tat org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.finishRefresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:164)\r\n\tat org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:551)\r\n\tat org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:142)\r\n\tat org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.web.server.ManagementContextAutoConfiguration$DifferentManagementContextConfiguration.afterSingletonsInstantiated(ManagementContextAutoConfiguration.java:151)\r\n\tat org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:776)\r\n\tat org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:867)\r\n\tat org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:548)\r\n\tat org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:142)\r\n\tat org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:754)\r\n\tat org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:386)\r\n\tat org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:307)\r\n\tat ***********)\r\nCaused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Protocol handler start failed\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.startInternal(Connector.java:1020)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)\r\n\t... 16 common frames omitted\r\nCaused by: java.net.BindException: Address already in use: bind\r\n\tat sun.nio.ch.Net.bind0(Native Method)\r\n\tat sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Unknown Source)\r\n\tat sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Unknown Source)\r\n\tat sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.bind(Unknown Source)\r\n\tat sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketAdaptor.bind(Unknown Source)\r\n\tat org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint.bind(NioEndpoint.java:219)\r\n\tat org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractEndpoint.start(AbstractEndpoint.java:1160)\r\n\tat org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.start(AbstractProtocol.java:591)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.startInternal(Connector.java:1018)\r\n\t... 17 common frames omitted\r\n\r\n"}
{"mdc":{},"timestamp":"2020-05-16 11:20:07.417","level":"ERROR","logger":"org.springframework.boot.diagnostics.LoggingFailureAnalysisReporter","message":"\r\n\r\n***************************\r\nAPPLICATION FAILED TO START\r\n***************************\r\n\r\nDescription:\r\n\r\nThe Tomcat connector configured to listen on port 8081 failed to start. The port may already be in use or the connector may be misconfigured.\r\n\r\nAction:\r\n\r\nVerify the connector's configuration, identify and stop any process that's listening on port 8081, or configure this application to listen on another port.\r\n","exception":""}

Comment: Found the solution :
To Change the STS Tomcat Server port:
 >> Go to Run configuration
 >> Open Spring Boot Tab 
 >> In Override Properties section copy below command to specify the port
  management.server.port=8082

Answer (score 1):

Two possible reasons:
1. Tomcat is not honoring the `-Dserver.port=` argument. Do note that `-D` is a JVM startup argument that, in this case, sets the `server.port` system variable. If you append `-Dserver.port` to the end of the Tomcat startup command, it might be interpreted as a command line argument for the Tomcat process. Try moving it before the Tomcat class name so you're sure it's picked up as a command line argument for the JVM (`java -Dserver.port=x tomcat.class.name`)
2. There is another listener configured in Tomcat (for example, an AJP connector). Look for port 8081 in Tomcat's `server.xml` and either change it there or find the respective command line argument to set this to another port when starting up.